# My program gives an index out of bounds error

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
int i=0;    
while(!a.isEmpty()) {         
    if(a.toCharArray()[i]==' ') { 
        System.out.println(a.toCharArray()[i]);         
    }         
    i++;     
}
```

When I run this program it's giving me an error: index out of bounds. How can I solve it?

Comment: Why would a not be empty (or ever become empty)?

Comment: At least include the stack trace in the question.

Comment: Not sure what a is, but you never remove anything from it, so eventually you will run off the end -- it will never go empty.

Comment: Use `a.charAt(i)` instead of `a.toCharArray()[i]`. It is a trillion times better for performance :)

Answer (score 5):

You're not changing `a` in the loop, so `a.isEmpty()` will not change and you'll continue looping until `i` goes out of bounds. Did you mean:

```
while (i < a.length()) {
```

And as an aside, `a.toCharArray()[i]` can (and should) simply be `a.charAt(i)` (as @MartijnCourteaux also points out).

Answer (score 2):

There are already a couple of answers that give solutions to the problem. This answer is about how you could have found the problem yourself.

Most array index out of bounds errors in loops are due to incorrect loop condition, so that the condition goes on being true even after the index has reached the end of the loop. Your loop condition did not depend on `i`, so the only way it could change from `true` to `false` is if `a` were changing inside the loop.

If you expected `a` to change, you should have put `System.out.println(a)` inside the loop, and monitored the value of `a`. You would have seen it not change.

Alternatively, if the `isEmpty` test were a typo, and you meant to test something that depends on `i`, desk checking your loop condition should have found it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your loop to this instead:

```
char[] c=a.toCharArray();
for(i=0; i<c.length; i++){
```